# Mule - dynamically create extra soap inbound endpoints

Tags: mule

We have a flow defined in xml with an http inbound-point (soap) listening on port 38001. We want to scale the solution to x parallel flows, on port 38002, 38003, and so on. The number will be defined in a properties file. Updating the number of flows will require a restart.

One solution to this problem is to copy-paste the < flow />. But maybe there is a programatic or dynamic solution?

We are using mule-3.3.1 with Java 7

Comment: Have you considered generating these flows as part of your project build?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by creating multiple identical flows with different ports? This isn't going to allow Mule to process any more requests - is there a different goal here?

Comment: The component listens on port 38001 for requests which are then processed and forwarded on to an external component A; and it listens on port 38002 for requests which are then processed and forwarded on to external component B. The processing is identical in each case.

Comment: It seems natural to see these as two separate mule components, implemented in the same executable but with different configurations. The solution I have now implemented has only one component, but with parallel flows defined within it. And to be complete I should point out that I am also aware of a sister project which dynamically creates flows from configuration using a groovy template [link]https://github.com/skltp/ei/blob/master/modules/intsvc/src/main/java/se/skltp/ei/intsvc/dynamicFlows/CreateDynamicFlows.java[link]